# DOMException: Document.querySelectorAll: 'body*:not(script):not(style):not(title)' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

in my vue app I want to search for a word in the DOM and highlight/scroll to that word, but I'm getting the following error in console:

```
DOMException: Document.querySelectorAll: 'body*:not(script):not(style):not(title)' is not a valid selector
```

My search method:

```
search() 
    { 
        const matches = document.querySelectorAll("body*:not(script):not(style):not(title)"); 

        for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) 
        { 
        const element = matches[i]; 
        if (element.textContent.includes(searchTerm)) 
        { 
            if(i == 0)
            {
                element.scrollIntoView();
            }
            console.log('Found'); 
        } 
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

since you are getting css selector syntax error add `space` after `body`:

```
document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(script):not(style):not(title)");
```

or small:

```
document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(script,style,title)");
```